# cannot encode accents in sender name | gmail API

Tags: node.js, email, encoding, gmail

I cannot encode accents in sender's name using gmail API.
Did try several encoding methods and still interprets 'é' as 'Ã©'

```html
request.post({
      url: USERS_URL + email + '/messages/send',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      json: true,
      body: createEmail(emailOptions)
    });
```

```html
const createEmail = ({sender, to, ccs, bccs, subject, emailBody}) => {
  subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString('base64')}?=`;
  // sender = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(sender).toString('base64')}?=`;
  const message = `from: ${sender}\nto: ${to}${(ccs && ccs.length > 0) ? '\ncc:' + ccs : ''}${(bccs && bccs.length > 0) ? '\nbcc:' + bccs : ''}\nsubject: ${subject}\ncontent-transfer-encoding: base64\nContent-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'\n\n ${emailBody}`;
  let buff = new Buffer.from(message);
  return {
    raw: buff
      .toString('base64')
      //html :
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_')
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved! you will have to do the encoding to the name part only in sender and

```html
const createEmail = ({to, ccs, bccs, subject, emailBody, email, name}) => {
  subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString('base64')}?=`;
  let sender = '"' + `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(name).toString('base64')}?=` + '"' + ' <' + email + '>';
  const message = `from: ${sender}\ncontent-transfer-encoding: base64\nContent-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'\nto: ${to}${(ccs && ccs.length > 0) ? '\ncc:' + ccs : ''}${(bccs && bccs.length > 0) ? '\nbcc:' + bccs : ''}\nsubject: ${subject}\ncontent-transfer-encoding: base64\nContent-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'\n\n ${emailBody}`;
  let buff = new Buffer.from(message);
  return {
    raw: buff
      .toString('base64')
      //html :
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_')
  };
};
```